# select distinct records based on a match and ignore duplicate id

Tags: mysql

I would like to get all records from Table 1 and its corresponding maximum status and its corresponding tier information from Table 2. I tried left join for this problem but I am not sure how to eliminate duplicate ID's

Example

```
Table 1

id  tier  source
1   54    AA
1   56    BB
2   45    AA
2   50    BB
3   10    AA
4   12    ZZ
6   10    MM
```

Table 2

```
id  status source
1   3      AA
1   2      AA
1   1      BB
2   3      BB
3   3      AA
5   2      BB
6   2      MM
```

My Expected output

```
id tier status source
1  54   3      AA
2  50   3      BB
3  10   3      AA
4  12   NULL   ZZ
6  10   2      MM
```

Tried Query

```
select t1.id, t1.tier, max(t2.status), t2.source
from t1
left join t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.source = t2.source
```

Comment: Where are the attempted queries?

Comment: What's your mysql version

Comment: I use data bricks

Comment: I mean your version of mysql `select VERSION();`

Comment: 3.0.1 is the version

Comment: You mean your MySQL version is from 1995-1996 period?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try group by t1.id?

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.tier, t2.status, t2.source
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.source = t2.source
WHERE t2.status = (SELECT MAX(status) FROM t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.source = t1.source)
```